# Validates allow_blank of multiple columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I validate Realty objects depending on their `active_state`, so if it's *pending*, multiple fields are allowed to be `blank`.

```
with_options :if => Proc.new { |a| a.active_state == 'pending'} do |realty|
  realty.validates :street, :length => {:in => 1..100}, :allow_blank => true
  realty.validates :postalcode, :numericality => {:only_integer => true}, :length => {:in => 4..5}, :allow_blank => true
  realty.validates :city, :length => {:in => 1..50}, :allow_blank => true
  realty.validates :description, :length => {:maximum => 8000}, :allow_blank => true
  realty.validates :leasing_costs, :numericality => {:only_integer => true}, :length => {:in => 1..9}, :allow_blank => true
end

with_options :if => Proc.new { |a| a.active_state != 'pending'} do |realty|
  realty.validates :street, :length => {:in => 1..100}
  realty.validates :postalcode, :numericality => {:only_integer => true}, :length => {:in => 4..5}
  realty.validates :city, :length => {:in => 1..50}
  realty.validates :description, :length => {:maximum => 8000}
  realty.validates :leasing_costs, :numericality => {:only_integer => true}, :length => {:in => 1..9}
end
```

The only difference are those `:allow_blank => true` options.

I want to make this code more dry, so my attempt would be to use the normal validations block once:

```
validates :street, :length => {:in => 1..100}
validates :postalcode, :numericality => {:only_integer => true}, :length => {:in => 4..5}
validates :city, :length => {:in => 1..50}
validates :description, :length => {:maximum => 8000}
validates :leasing_costs, :numericality => {:only_integer => true}, :length => {:in => 1..9}
```

and then simply call some function on all of those fields in case the state is *pending*:

```
with_options :if => Proc.new { |a| a.active_state == 'pending'} do |realty|
  realty.allow_blank_of :street, :postalcode, :city, :description, :leasing_costs
end
```

Similar to all those `validates_uniqueness_of :x, :y, :z` methods.

I couldn't find a function to fit my need. How can I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [pdobb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24714466/2235594)

> However, you can achieve the same result using the :if
>   option since :allow_blank is essentially a way of saying "if the
>   attribute is blank then don't run this validation requirement".

Based on pdobbs explanation what `allow_blank => true` actually does, I could narrow the validations down to:

```
validates :street, :length => {:in => 1..100}, :unless => :pending?
validates :postalcode, :numericality => {:only_integer => true}, :length => {:in => 4..5}, :unless => :pending?
validates :city, :length => {:in => 1..50}, :unless => :pending?
validates :description, :length => {:maximum => 8000}, :unless => :pending?
validates :leasing_costs, :numericality => {:only_integer => true}, :length => {:in => 1..9}, :unless => :pending?

def pending?
   active_state == "pending"
end
```

So I simply skip all of those validations if the `active_state` is "pending".

Allot more DRY :)

Comment: Ahh. Great. You could still keep the `with_options` block in this case then, if you wanted: `with_options unless: :pending? do |realty|`. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice if the `:allow_blank` option took a proc, but I don't think it does. However, you can achieve the same result using the `:if` option since `:allow_blank` is essentially a way of saying "if the attribute is blank then don't run this validation requirement". So try this:

```
with_options :if => Proc.new { |a| a.active_state == 'pending' ? a.present? : true } do |realty|
  realty.validates :street, :length => {:in => 1..100}
  realty.validates :postalcode, :numericality => {:only_integer => true}, :length => {:in => 4..5}
  realty.validates :city, :length => {:in => 1..50}
  realty.validates :description, :length => {:maximum => 8000}
  realty.validates :leasing_costs, :numericality => {:only_integer => true}, :length => {:in => 1..9}
end
```

The proc in this case is saying... if the `active_state` is `'pending'` and the attribute is present then execute this validation. But if the `active_state` is not `'pending'` then the attribute isn't allowed to be blank so always run the validation. I hope I got that logic right based on your needs.

Comment: Hey pdobb, thanks for your attempt. This does not work as it always calls the validation, so adding the `active_state => "pending"` does not skip the validation as it should. If there is `a.active_state == 'pending'` then `a.present?` will always return `true`

Comment: Are you saying the approach is wrong too, or just the conditional logic inside the proc?

Comment: I'm playing around with the approach, but couldn't find any logic that would fit.

Comment: I see what you're saying now. Because `a` isn't the attribute itself, and it's not obvious how to access the value in the attribute you're validating from a `with_options` block. It could work if you had one `if` option per validation, though. You could define a special proc to DRY this up. I'll add an edit to show what I'd try next.

Comment: Hey I just added an answer that worked :) Based off your explanation on what `:allow_blank` does

Answer (score 0):

I haven't ran this, but I *think* this may work

```
before_commit :build_callback_validator, :on => :create

def build_callback_validator
  validates :street, :length => {:in => 1..100}
  validates :postalcode, :numericality => {:only_integer => true}, :length => {:in => 4..5}
  validates :city, :length => {:in => 1..50}
  validates :description, :length => {:maximum => 8000}
  validates :leasing_costs, :numericality => {:only_integer => true}, :length => {:in => 1..9}
  if self.active_state != 'pending'
    self.allow_blank_of :street, :postalcode, :city, :description, :leasing_costs
  end
end
```